# How To Save The State Of the CheckBox In A ListView Which Uses MultiChoiceModeListener?

Tags: android, android-listview

We have a listview which uses a MultiChoiceModeListener.

```
final ArrayAdapter<String > pings = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, all);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setAdapter(pings);
```

Through this the layout looks like:
[image]

For each item in the listview when it is clicked we change a boolean variable(From true to false and vice versa).
But on clicking the back button and returning. The boolean value has the correct
value but the checkbox isnt ticked.
I think that we have to use SavedInstanceState() and RestoreInstanceState() to achieve this, but how do programmatically tick the checkbox depending on the boolean value.(As this isn't a general checkbox widget)

Comment: use [setItemChecked](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html) to select item

Comment: I didn't understand on what object to use setItemChecked on. Could you please provide some sample code?

Comment: on ListView object, something like `lv.setItemChecked(intPosition, isChecked)`

Comment: You have to customize the adapter..

Comment: Is there any way to do it without customizing the adapter?

Comment: The lv.setItemChecked worked :D